# systemd can not import environment variables like $SSH_AUTH_SOCK

Tags: service, emacs, environment, gnupg, systemd

I wrote a service file in user space of systemd for starting up emacs daemon. This works quite well. But on startup of emacsclient I let decrypt my diary file. For that I have running gpg-agent. Normally when emacs is started pineentry-gtk pops up and prompts me for my private key password. But started the daemon with systemd the environment variables $SSH_AUTH_SOCKET, $GPG_AGENT_INFO and SSH_AGENT_PID are not known. Therefore no pineentry-gtk pops up. Several approaches to feed systemd from the system arround got stucked. I want to use a dynamical approach NOT putting in an absolute path.

I defined a systemd EnvironmentFile and put in there

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCKET=${SSH_AUTH_SOCKET}
```

and included the file in emacs.sevice. Investigating here I found  [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1193453) link and can't imagine that this is true. That means environment settings in a service/unit file is an other story as setting it in environment file. They can't see each other. What sense makes then an evironment file?

Next step was to import the environment variables from my at login time sourced ~/.bash_profile like this.

```
systemctl --user import-environment GPG_AGENT_INFO
systemctl --user import-environment SSH_AUTH_SOCKET
systemctl --user import-environment SSH_AGENT_PID
```

After login I took a look in order to see whether systemd got the environment variables or not. I got this by typing

```
systemctl --user show-environmet

DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
GPG_AGENT_INFO=${GPG_AGENT_INFO}
HOME=/home/xxxx
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LOGNAME=xxxx
PATH=/home/xxxx/bin:~/.emacs.d/shell-scripts: .........
AUTH_SOCK=${SSH_AUTH_SOCKET}
USER=xxxx
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
```

But starting emacs daemon within systemd environment shows me the same symptoms.

Next step was to import the variables directly in the unit/service file like this.

```
[Unit]
Description=Emacs: the extensible, self-documenting text editor

[Service]
# loading default environment for systemd in user space
EnvironmentFile=%h/.config/systemd/xxxx-default-evironment.env

Type=forking
ExecStartPre=/bin/systemctl --user import-environment SSH_AUTH_SOCKET
ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --daemon
ExecStartPost=/bin/systemctl --user set-environment    SSH_AUTH_SOCK=${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}
ExecStop=/usr/bin/emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)"

Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=non-graphical.target
```

No sucess in this approach as well. By the way can't believe that it is so difficult to publish some environment variables of the **SYSTEM** to **SYSTEM(D)**.

Any answers are very welcome.

Thanks 
Falk

Comment: Have you tried to import your environment variables using the https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell package?

Comment: I don't know much about systemd, but I would imagine that running `systemctl --user import-environment` in your `.bashrc` is happening *later* than systemd starting Emacs?  In which case it's not useful, as Emacs has already acquired its environment, which will not include those values?

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice utility called keychain that will start a ssh-agent/gpg-agent, and then dump the env vars to a file.  Shells can just source the file to get the vars, and other programs like Emacs can parse the file to get the vars.  For Emacs, there's a keychain-environment package in Melpa.

```
# .bash_profile
type keychain >&/dev/null \
    && keychain --agents ssh
```

---

```
# .bashrc
[ -f $HOME/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh ] \
    && . $HOME/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh
```

---

```
;; init.el
(when (require 'keychain-environment nil 'noerror)
  (keychain-refresh-environment))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example has a typo, the environmental variable you need is SSH_AUTH_SOCK not SSH_AUTH_SOCKET. Also your ExecStartPre will run as part of the same environment as the ExecStart, so you can't use import there.

I was able to use an example from [ssh-find-agent](https://github.com/wwalker/ssh-find-agent/blob/master/ssh-find-agent.sh#L37) to set SSH_AUTH_SOCK in the systemd user service manager by locating the socket file. This isn't bulletproof but seems to work well for me so far. Also keep in mind using import-environment or set-environment will enable the value for ALL services, or in this case all user services (because of --user). If you don't want that, probably best to move the logic into a wrapping script and execute that instead of the service directly.

Here is an example of using sshfs as part of a systemd user service unit:

```
# Create mount directory and make sure user has correct permissions
sudo mkdir /mnt/myserver
sudo chown $USER:$USER /mnt/myserver

# Create the following file:
systemctl --user cat sshfs-myserver.service 
# /home/USERNAME/.config/systemd/user/sshfs-myserver.service
[Unit]
AssertPathExists=/mnt/myserver

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "systemctl --user set-environment SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(find /tmp/ -type s -name agent.* 2> /dev/null | grep -o '/tmp/ssh-.*/agent.*')"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sshfs -o sshfs_debug root@myserver:/ /mnt/myserver
Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target


# Then enable service, run, and check status/env
systemctl --user enable ssh-myserver
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user start sshfs-myserver
systemctl --user show-environment
systemctl --user status sshfs-myserver
```

Normally you would just use a systemd mount unit with [Type=fuse.sshfs](https://www.buggycoder.com/mount-remote-fs-sshfs-systemd/), but they seem to require running the mount command as root (didn't work when I tried in a --user unit)